# laravel 5.4 validate array with custom rule

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

I'm having trouble validating an array of fields that requires a custom rule. I have the following validator:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'order'        => 'required',
     'service_id.*' => Rule::unique('order_services')->where('order_id', $request->order),
     'due_date.*'   => 'required|date',
     'vendor'   => 'required|integer',
     'instructions' => 'string|nullable',
     'lock_box' => 'string|nullable',
  ]);
```

The due date array validates just fine, but the service id returns the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'service_id.0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `order_services` where `service_id`.`0` = 10 and `order_id` = 100f)
```

The service id rule prevents duplicate records with the same order number and service id

The rule works as expected when validating a single service ID, I'm just not sure how to validate multiple service IDs at the same time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Laravel uses key for `unique` role and because it's an array, keys are 0, 1, 2 and so on. The solution is adding column name for unique rule like this:

```
Rule::unique('order_services', 'id')->where('order_id', $request->order),
```

Obviously in your case you might need other column name than `id` (it depends on your application)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using Rule::unique('order_services', 'service_id')->where('order_id', $request->order),